# How to allow the user to create three grids filterable between them?

Tags: filter, grid

It's hard to be clear so I'll try to explain with a concrete example.

I need three grids. **Category**, **Sourcing** and **Service**. I need to display them at the same time with all the related data but I also have to allow users to filter the grid. Each grid should be filtered by others grids. Here is some example of what should be answered by these grid :

- What is Sourcing distribution by Category ?
- For each of theses Sourcing, what's the Services distribution ?
- What is the Category distribution by Service ? By Sourcing ? Etc.

It sounds like Excel pivot table and I don't know how to create an understandable UI.

I tough about a grid imbrication hierarchy but I don't know how to change the parameters when I expand each line.

Example : http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid/hierarchyajax

The readability of this kind of grid is poor and I don't know how to change properly the order of the grids (Client -> Order -> Product, to Order -> Product -> Client or Prodduct -> Client -> Order, etc.).

Do you have some ideas in order to answer to this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to have the main list on the page and with a layer on top show the contents of that item, then, the contents of the layer would be sorted according to the columns or controls that you provide.

Another way, if the amount of data is too much or too complex, is to use one page per item, let say, one page per category and on each one show the relevant data; again, if that data is still too complex, use another page for the next level of subcategory, if it's not too complex, use a layer on top to show the rest of the data.

If you use this system, or any other alternative with multiple pages, remember to use something like breadcrumbs to allow the user to know at all times where he is. You can also combine the breadcrumbs system with a select control, so instead of having to go back to the previous level, he can choose from a list.

If the data is important, and I'm assuming it is, you have to make the process of getting there as easy as possible. One page per item is usually the simplest and most intuitive way.